# JSF boolean output

Tags: jsf, rendering, boolean

Is there a way in JSF to output some text based on a boolean?
For example:
h:outputText value="Black" rendered="#{bean.isBlack}"

The bean property is called isBlack not getIsBlack...I dont want to rename this.

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 2):

The expression `#{bean.black}` should do it.

The *Unified Expression Language* can resolve properties using [JavaBean](http://java.sun.com/beans) conventions ([see BeanELResolver](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/el/package-summary.html)). The *UEL* spec is currently maintained as part of the [JSP spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245).